# Draw in the empire

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

What happens when it's a draw in the empire between two princes, and no one is the Emperor of the HRE? The next Emperor is elected randomly?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't play often in the Empire and it never happened to me, but I found the answer on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/eu4/comments/1w88e2/how_are_elector_ties_resolved/)

> A tie with the Emperor results in the Emperor staying elected.
>   A tie with anyone else gets resolved with a prestige check, IIRC.
>   For how to rush to Erbkaisertum, adding territory and winning defensive wars via "Enforce Peace" should do it.